# action="/i18n/setlang/" does not redirect to any page

Tags: django, google-app-engine, internationalization, django-views

I have followed the django documentation[1] to implement i18n on a "hello word" kind of google app engine website.

unfortunately, after reading dozens of html pages, django and appengine documentation I can't figure out what is happening:

- changing the language code into the django_settings.py do change the language of the page and update a dropdown with the current language (i.e. LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr' or 'es' or 'en')
- change the dropdown and clicking on "change language" do lead to a "error 404" and the URL shows http:///i18n/setlang/

where can I find a list of django middlewares that app engine use by default? this might help me to digg deeper.

technical requirements (we don't plan to upgrade before i18n works :-) :

- python 2.5.4
- google app engine 1.6.2
- Django 1.2

[1] [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/]

[2] [cssjanus.googlecode.com] a piece of code that do exactly what I want to do. but I miss a small trick

index.html contains this

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/MainPage">
    <select name="language">
        {% for lang in LANGUAGES %} <option value="{{ lang.0 }}"
            {% ifequal LANGUAGE_CODE lang.0 %}
            selected="selected"
            {% endifequal %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Change Language" %}">
</form>
```

app.yaml:

```
application: i18n
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: .*
  script: helloworld.py`
```

django_seetings.py

```
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'
USE_I18N = True

gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
  ('en', gettext('English')),
  ('fr', gettext('French')),
  ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions', 
)
SESSION_ENGINE = 'gae_sessions'
```

helloworld.py (I don't use urls.py)

```
# coding=UTF-8

# Standard Python imports.
import os
import sys
import logging
import __builtin__

# Google App Hosting imports.
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')

# Enable info logging by the app (this is separate from appserver's
# logging).
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Must set this env var *before* importing any part of Django.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_settings'

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util 
# Import the part of Django that we use here.


from google.appengine.ext import webapp

from views import MainPage

from django.conf.urls.defaults import include

def main():
    # Create a Django application for WSGI
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),                                        
                                    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
                                     ], debug=True)


    # Run the WSGI CGI handler with that application.
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

views.py

```
'''
Created on Apr 24, 2012

@author:xxxx
'''
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from django.utils.translation import ugettext #ok

from django import http
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import django_settings  
from django.utils.translation import check_for_language
#from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

#def MainPage(request):

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'helloworld': ugettext("helloworld!"),
            'title': ugettext("home page"),
        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
        #return render_to_response('index.html', template_values)
```

helloworld.py

```
# coding=UTF-8

# Standard Python imports.
import os
import sys
import logging
import __builtin__

# Google App Hosting imports.
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')

# Enable info logging by the app (this is separate from appserver's
# logging).
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Must set this env var *before* importing any part of Django.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_settings'

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util 
 # Import the part of Django that we use here.


from google.appengine.ext import webapp

from views import MainPage

from django.conf.urls.defaults import include

def main():
    # Create a Django application for WSGI
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),                                        
                                        (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
                                         ], debug=True)


    # Run the WSGI CGI handler with that application.
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Show your urls.py and views.py.

Comment: All info you can always find on djangoproject.com. Here is about [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware)

Comment: If you make a new application, I strongly recommend you to use Python 2.7 on app engine. So you can more easily use third party libraries like django (see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27#Configuring_Libraries)

Comment: denis, I have added the source code you have requested helloworld.py (containing the url patterns)

Comment: Denis thanks for the link to middleware but I have read it dozens of times :-) it didn't help. the question is "why does the set_language() is never called"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing django routing with webapp's one. I don't think you can use statement like `include('django.conf.urls.i18n')` in the initialization process of `webapp.WSGIApplication`.

Additionally, as greg says, I also recommend using Python2.7 runtime, because it is much easier for you to use django(Believe me, it's super easy) with the new runtime.

*Updated: added a procedure for running django-1.3 with Python2.7 runtime*

Here is a rough procedure to make django work with python2.7 runtime.

**Create a project**

```
$ env PYTHONPATH=/somewhere/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3 \
   python /somewhere/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/bin/django-admin.py\
   startproject my_django_project
$ cd my_django_project
```

You can use settings.py for your django settings file by configuring
an env_variables in your app.yaml.

**Create an app.yaml**

```
application: tmatsuo-hr
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'settings'

handlers:
- url: /.*                                                                                                                                                     
  script: main.app                                                                                                                                             

libraries:                                                                                                                                                     
- name: django                                                                                                                                                 
  version: 1.3
```

**Create your django app**

```
$ env PYTHONPATH=/somewhere/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3 \
   python manage.py startapp myapp
```

**Create your main.py**

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

app = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**Configure your settings.py**

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
Add 'myapp' to your INSTALLED_APPS
```

**Configure urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index', name='index'),
```

**Create your views at myapp/views.py**

```
# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World!')
```

**Done. You should be able to configure this project in the same way as usual django applications.**

However, you can not use Django's model because it needs SQL backends. If you'd like to do so, go check django-nonrel, or consider using django with CloudSQL.

Comment: Takashi, thank you for the explanation and the code but I don't think it answers to my question. 1st: I don't plan to move to migrate my application to python2.7 anytime soon. 2nd: the CSS Janus project (see my original post-i have included the link) do use the django routing and it works. there is a little trick I miss somewhere.

Comment: Where is the code which use django routing in WSGIApplication?

Comment: I have added the helloword.py at the end of the post. thanks for your time.

Comment: No. You said 'the CSS Janus project do use the django routing and it works.' I want to see the working example.

Comment: I know that. But I couldn't find the real example you're saying. Could you point me out the real code example?

Comment: If your question is "why does the set_language() is never called?", my answer is a proper one. In other words, it's because your django setting is broken. You need to set up django correctly first, and then, try to use i18n feature, and if you still see the problem, please create another question.

Comment: follow the link and click source > browse > trunk

Comment: I can just see the way the cssjanus project uses django is completely different from what you're doing; http://code.google.com/p/cssjanus/source/browse/trunk/django_bootstrap.py. Please use django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler instead of webapp.WSGIApplication, like cssjanus project and I do.

Comment: I have tried with djanco.core.handlers.... too but it didn't work neither. I agree that it is the main difference but when I used this class instead of the webapp.WSGIApplication, it didn't work. I'll try  to change my code again. A new question will popup then: is  django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler as scalable as webapp.WSGIApplication?

Comment: Please create another question. This comment feature is just a complement to improve original question. Additionally, if you understand your django setting is broken now, can you accept this answer?

Comment: Takashi, I will accept it as soon as the code works :-) I have made some changes and indeed it is going to the right direction: i18n/setlang does not generate a 404 anymore. but still, the translation does not work :-(